# Linux: How to simulate several IP- and MAC-Addresses for networktesting in one linux box

Tags: linux-networking, bridge

I want to test a network with one linux-box which should get 100 different IP-Addresses, each with an own MAC which should be used as source MAC-address when communicating to other devices.

I've scripted this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 0 10 `; do 
    hex=`perl -e "printf ('%02X', $i)"`
    echo tap$i / $hex
    ip link add link eth0 address 00:00:13:37:00:$hex eth0-$i type macvlan
done
sleep 2
for i in `seq 0 10 `; do
    echo eth0-$i ip
    while ! ifconfig eth0-$i &>/dev/null; do
        sleep 1
    done
    ii=`expr $i + 100`
    ip addr add 10.254.251.$ii/24 dev eth0-$i
    ifconfig eth0-$i up
done
```

then i get my devices with own IP and own MAC-Address.

But when from outside anyone ARPs for one of my IP-Addresses the linux hosts answers multiple times through eth0 with all my virtual addresses, the other device then inserts the last one in its ARP-Table.

```
23:43:22.764080 00:24:43:8f:e5:39 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 10.254.251.100 tell 10.254.251.1, length 46
23:43:22.764340 b8:27:eb:b3:e1:36 > 00:24:43:8f:e5:39, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 10.254.251.100 is-at b8:27:eb:b3:e1:36, length 28
23:43:22.764442 00:00:13:37:00:00 > 00:24:43:8f:e5:39, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 10.254.251.100 is-at 00:00:13:37:00:00, length 28
23:43:22.764642 00:00:13:37:00:01 > 00:24:43:8f:e5:39, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 10.254.251.100 is-at 00:00:13:37:00:01, length 28
23:43:22.764733 00:00:13:37:00:02 > 00:24:43:8f:e5:39, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 10.254.251.100 is-at 00:00:13:37:00:02, length 28
23:43:22.764929 00:00:13:37:00:03 > 00:24:43:8f:e5:39, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 10.254.251.100 is-at 00:00:13:37:00:03, length 28
23:43:22.765071 00:00:13:37:00:04 > 00:24:43:8f:e5:39, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 10.254.251.100 is-at 00:00:13:37:00:04, length 28
23:43:22.765208 00:00:13:37:00:05 > 00:24:43:8f:e5:39, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 10.254.251.100 is-at 00:00:13:37:00:05, length 28
23:43:22.765342 00:00:13:37:00:06 > 00:24:43:8f:e5:39, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 10.254.251.100 is-at 00:00:13:37:00:06, length 28
23:43:22.765476 00:00:13:37:00:07 > 00:24:43:8f:e5:39, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 10.254.251.100 is-at 00:00:13:37:00:07, length 28
23:43:22.765560 00:00:13:37:00:08 > 00:24:43:8f:e5:39, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 10.254.251.100 is-at 00:00:13:37:00:08, length 28
23:43:22.765713 00:00:13:37:00:09 > 00:24:43:8f:e5:39, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 10.254.251.100 is-at 00:00:13:37:00:09, length 28
23:43:22.765845 00:00:13:37:00:0a > 00:24:43:8f:e5:39, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 10.254.251.100 is-at 00:00:13:37:00:0a, length 28
23:43:22.767375 00:24:43:8f:e5:39 > b8:27:eb:b3:e1:36, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.254.251.1 > 10.254.251.100: ICMP echo request, id 2984, seq 0, length 64
23:43:22.767561 b8:27:eb:b3:e1:36 > 00:24:43:8f:e5:39, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.254.251.100 > 10.254.251.1: ICMP echo reply, id 2984, seq 0, length 64
```

Has anyone an idea for me how to setup? iIs macvlan the wrong way?

Using a linux brige i can do a similar setup, but the host replies for all IPs with the physical MAC of the outgoing interface.

Comment: Does it make sense to call something as fat as perl just for a `printf` hex conversion if `printf` is both a bash builtin and a seperate program (by a factor 40 smaller than perl)?

Answer (score 1):

[Have a look at arp_filter and arp_ignore](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt).

`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/arp_filter`, `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/arp_ignore`

Comment: thanks, good idea, but no success. i can stop the multiple answers, but then only the physical MAC answers. I've also played around with 'arp_announce', no success

Comment: This worked for me. On the physical and all linked macvlan interfaces I had arp_filter = 0, arp_ignore = 1, arp_announce = 2 (not strictly necessary for fixing arp responses, but helps prevent announcing out with the wrong MAC). I also initially got the same behaviour as you (only physical MAC responding) when arp_filter was set to 1.